# how do I assign an int to a string with stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

How do I assign an `int` to a `string` with `stringstream`?

The "`stringstream(mystr2) << b;`" doesn't assign `b` to `mystr2` in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mystr = "1204";
    int a;
    stringstream(mystr) >> a;
    cout << a << endl; // prints 1204

    int b = 10;
    string mystr2;
    stringstream(mystr2) << b;
    cout << mystr2 << endl; // prints nothing
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << a;
ss >> mystr;

ss.clear();
ss << b;
ss >> mystr2;
```

Comment: Hmm, he had the trouble with the second part, not the first, no? :) 'b' would have been clearer in there with mystr2.

Answer (score 1):

```
int b = 10;
string mystr2;
stringstream ss;
ss << b;
cout << ss.str() << endl; // prints 10
```

Comment: You still have an extra space in there. ;-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp, sorry, when I copied, I did not clean the extra `<<`.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a string stream with the ctor `stringstream(mystr2)` the `mystr2` is copied as the initial content of the buffer. `mystr2` is not modified by subsequent operations on the stream.

To get the content of the stream you can use the `str` method:

```
int b = 10;
string mystr2;
stringstream ss = stringstream(mystr2);  
ss << b;
cout << mystr2.str() << endl;
```

See [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) and [str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str) method.

Answer (score 0):

This will print out the '10' correctly below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string mystr = "1204";
    int a;
    stringstream(mystr) >> a;
    cout << a << endl; // prints 1204

    int b = 10;
    string mystr2;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << b;
    ss >> mystr2;
    cout << mystr2 << endl; // prints 10
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your literal question is:

```
int b = 10;
std::string mystr2 = static_cast<stringstream &>(stringstream()<<b).str();
cout << mystr2 << endl;
```